# Qt - Setting the buddies

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

In `QtDesigner`, what is the purpose of `Edit Buddies`? When should we enter such mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-buddy-mode.html), it is for linking labels to their corresponding input controls.